# Get loop value when condition is true in robotframework

Tags: for-loop, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework, I want to get loop value when the condition is true. Below I mention sample code.

```
   FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    1    10
        Run Keyword If    ${INDEX}==5
   END
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the call to a keyword, and I assume you don't want to continue the loop after it, so for example:

```
FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    1    10
    Run Keyword If    ${INDEX}==5    Run Keywords    No Operation    Exit For Loop
END
Log    For loop variable is ${INDEX}
```